# How to create the side side on tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, uisearchbar

How do you create the tableview side bar? I'm not sure of the exact name for it. It contains letters that allow you to skip to certain headings?

Comment: Please refer to the following link on how to ask a stackoverflow question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called the index. Implement `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:`.